# is this the only way i can use object pools?

Tags: java, android, object-pooling

I've been looking into using Apache common pool for an android game im working on, however it seems object pooling doesn't work for generic classes.

So i believe i am left with two options for pooling.

1. I make every game object generic but alter their setup so objects have different starting properties, e.g. Mass, size, State, 3d body, etc.

or

2.I setup multiple smaller pools for each sub-type.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: You've asked two questions. Which is it?

Comment: Is it possible to inject in the properties objects to each of the "games"? GameObject(type, mass, size, state (contains 3d body, and game object properties like npc type, etc))

Comment: That way your not dealing with a generic, but possibly just passing a wrapped type into the wrapping "game object" class

Comment: I was using state just as part of a state machine but i see what you mean.